# Will my alarm still go off if my phone is on airplane mode?

Tags: alarm, airplane-mode

I'm trying to save battery but I need my alarm in the morning. Will it still go off if on airplane mode?

p.s. I have an HTC Inspire.

Comment: If you have an alarm app from the Amazon Appstore, you might have the opposite problem -- you might not be able to shut it *off*.  I had Gentle Alarm and the alarm service ran fine, but to shut it off it opened the app which attempted a DRM check.  The check failed due to no internet and the app closed, leaving the alarm running :P

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Airplane mode (flight mode) only disables your phone's signal transmitting functions, not the functions that don't require a signal to function.

Your alarm will still work.

Answer (score 3):

As @Jasir says. Your alarm will still work in Airplane mode.

Be careful as there is another setting on your phone.

Clock > Alarms > Menu > Settings > 'Alarm in silent mode'

You will need this ticked if you put your phone in silent (saving more battery) and still want the alarm to go off!

Answer (score 0):

Do a quick, simple test on your phone (that's what I did):

Put your phone on airplane mode, then set an alarm for 1 (one) minute into the future.  If done correctly, your alarm should sound off within 1 minute.  Then you know it works!

Answer (score 0):

Alarm clock **requires no Internet connection.**

So **yes,** alarm is still on with airplane/flight mode enabled

Answer (score 0):

Actually your phone time needs to occasionally access the network's time server to stay synced and that might affect your alarm.  I didnt wake up today because i set an alarm for 3 hrs, set airplane mode, and it never rang, but i can't really prove this now.

Comment: Your phone clock shouldn't go that wrong overnight: even without updates, it should be accurate to a few seconds per year. Most likely something else went wrong with your alarm.